# In Oracle SQL how do we avoid having to prepend the schema name?

Tags: sql, oracle

My boss just sent me a query that he runs like the following :

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM po_requisition_lines_all prl, 
    po_requisition_headers_all prha, 
    po_req_distributions_all prda,   /* ETC */
```

But this query won't run for me unless I prepend hte schema before the table names :

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM po.po_requisition_lines_all prl, 
    apps.po_requisition_headers_all prha, 
    userx.po_req_distributions_all prda,   /* ETC */
```

Is there a way in Oracle to avoid having to prepend the schema before the table-name?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.

1. Login as USERX, OR
2. alter session set current_schema = USERX, OR
3. create local synonyms on the tables in USERX for your account

Comment: that's 1, or 2, or 3 - not all 3 together :)

Comment: yes, i was in the midst of altering said answer after I read it back to myself. i'm used to having more than 30 seconds :)

Comment: You can also use public synonyms for user independent schemas.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - Not sure I follow. what/how is that done ?

Comment: `CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM MySynomym FOR mySchema.MyTable;` You must have the `CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM` system privilege to do so.

Comment: Public synonyms have a bit of a bad name, though. They're a technical solution, sure, but can lead to problems.